# JS При клике переключаться на следующий div

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции

Например есть

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<button>Вперёд</button>
<button>Назад</button>
```

Как правильно будет описана функция JS Чтобы получить следующий результат. 
При нажатии присваивается класс active к первому div , при повторном нажатии класс удаляется и присваивается к следующему диву. если нажать Назад , то действие идет в обратном порядке.

Comment: Вам надо на чистом Javascript или можно так же по Jquery

Comment: на jquery можно конечно! я думаю нужно задействовать счётчик может быть и делать echo например nth-child(1++) ну это пока в мыслях...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На скорую руку

```js
$(document).ready(function () {


 $('.next').on('click', function () {
  if ($('div.active').index() == -1) {
   $('.box div:first-child').addClass('active');
  } else {

   $('div.active').next('div').addClass('active');
   $('div.active').prev('div').removeClass('active');
  }

 });


 $('.prev').on('click', function () {
  if ($('div.active').index() == -1) {
   /* без действий */
  } else {

   $('div.active').prev('div').addClass('active');
   $('div.active').next('div').removeClass('active');
  }

 });


});
```

```css
.active{
background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<button class="prev">Назад</button>
<button class="next">Вперёд</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

```js
var i = 0;
document.getElementById('forward').onclick = function() {

  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].classList.remove("active");
  if(i == 3) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    i++;
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].classList.add("active");
}
document.getElementById('back').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].classList.remove("active");
  if(i == 0) {
    i = 3;
  } else {
    i--
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="active">1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<button id="forward">Вперёд</button>
<button id="back">Назад</button>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что не стоит жестко задавать значение `i = 3;`, лучше использовать длину массива, так как количество элементов может быть разное, а править каждый раз код будет не очень хорошо и блоки могут добавляться динамически.

Comment: да, но стоит добавить отдельный класс для блоков

Answer (score 4):

```js
let current = 0;
let setNewActive = function(duration) {
  let elements = document.getElementById('wrapper').getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      current = i;
    }
    elements[i].removeAttribute("class");
  }
  if (duration === 'up' && current > 0)
    current--;
  if (duration === 'down' && current < elements.length - 2)
    current++;
  elements[current].setAttribute('class', 'active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="active">1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>
    <button onclick="setNewActive('up')">Вперёд</button>
    <button onclick="setNewActive('down')">Назад</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Такая функция может быть правильно описана несколькими способами :)

Наиболее очевидный способ без лишних усложнений - с использованием [свойств элемента `previousElementSibling` и `nextElementSibling`](https://learn.javascript.ru/traversing-dom), которые указывают на соседние элементы того же уровня вложенности.

```js
var current, 
    first = document.querySelector('#container > div:first-child'), 
    last  = document.querySelector('#container > div:last-child'); 

var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button'); 
for (let btn of btns) 
  btn.addEventListener('click', onBtnClick); 

function onBtnClick(e) {
  if (current)
    current.classList.remove('active'); 
  switch (e.target.id) {
    case 'prev' : current = current ? current.previousElementSibling || last : last; break; 
    case 'next' : current = current ? current.nextElementSibling || first : first; break; 
    case 'first': current = first; break; 
    case 'last' : current = last; 
  }
  current.classList.add('active'); 
}
```

```css
body,
button {
  font: 16px sans-serif;
}

button { width: 64px; height: 2em; }
#container { display: flex; }

#container > div {
  flex: 0 0 50px; height: 50px; 
  margin: 5px; 
  background-color: #777; color: #fff; 
  text-align: center; line-height: 50px; 
  border: 3px solid #444;
}
#container > div.active { border-color: #d44; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<button id="first">⏪</button>
<button id="prev">◀</button>
<button id="next">▶</button>
<button id="last">⏩</button>
```